# Sharing implementations of extension functions between Float and Double in Kotlin

Tags: templates, kotlin, extension-methods

**NOTE: This question is not about generic classes, it's about generic functions.** (I don't believe it to be a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32883936/extension-functions-for-generic-classes-in-kotlin): it is more specific than that.)

In our project, we have a handful of utility functions to extend `Double` and `Float`, such as `toFixed` (inspired by `Javascript's Number.toFixed`)

```
fun Double.toFixed(digits: Int):String = java.lang.String.format("%.${digits}f", this)
fun Float.toFixed(digits: Int):String = java.lang.String.format("%.${digits}f", this)
```

As you can see, `Double.toFixed` and `Float.toFixed` have an identical implementation.

Because there are several other, more complicated extension functions like this, improvements and bug fixes in one version (say, `Double.toPrecision`) have to be manually kept in sync (with `Float.toPrecision`), which is boring and error prone.

I experimented with moving the duplicated implementations into a shared `<templated>` function, but (rightly) it can't access `this` in the context of an unbound function.

To illustrate, I was hoping for something like this:

```
private fun <T>toFixed(digits: Int):String = java.lang.String.format("%.${digits}f", this)
fun Double.toFixed = ::toFixed<Double>
fun Float.toFixed = ::toFixed<Float>
```

If any language can rock this, surely Kotlin can! Thoughts?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extension functions for generic classes in Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32883936/extension-functions-for-generic-classes-in-kotlin)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An extension on a generic type can be achieved by using `fun <T> T.toFixed(...)`. Doing that, `this` is accessible.

The Problem then is, that the extenstion can be used on any type! You can use upper bounds on your `T` to restrict it:

`fun <T: Number> T.toFixed(...)`

If you really have to restrict the extension to *only* `Float` *and* *Double* it's necessary to extend the concrete types only. Have a look at the Koltin `math` library in addition, might be helpful :) (Available with [1.2-Beta](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2017/09/kotlin-1-2-beta-is-out/)):
https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/1.2-Beta/js/js.libraries/src/core/math.kt